# Is there a cost associated with over using hidden on a CALayer?

Tags: iphone, calayer

Was wondering if someone might know the answer to this question - is there a cost associated with over hiding a layer.

For example, if a layer is already hidden, does calling layer.hidden = YES over and over have any more overhead than simply stepping through the call stack?  Is Cocoa smart enough to know that the layer is already hidden?

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     if ( characterLeftFlag ) {
          characterLeftView.layer.hidden = NO;
          characterRightView.layer.hidden = YES;
     }
     else {
          characterLeftView.layer.hidden = YES;
          characterRightView.layer.hidden = NO;
     }
}
```

Or do I need to always check to see if the layers visibility has changed and then call hidden?

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
     if ( characterLeftFlag && characterLeftView.layer.hidden ) {
          characterLeftView.layer.hidden = NO;
          characterRightView.layer.hidden = YES;
     }
     else if ( characterRightFlag && characterRightView.layer.hidden ) {
          characterLeftView.layer.hidden = YES;
          characterRightView.layer.hidden = NO;
     }
}
```

The first pattern allows closure on the conditional statement which results in better coding practice but does result in extra stack calls, while the second pattern is more explicit but results in a conditional statement that falls through.

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: Not necessarily.  This logic simply pushes the check down the stack.  The end result is better code since there is no fall through in the conditional statement.  The second pattern where you have to evaluate every possible condition still has to deal with the implicit state that the view is currently in the correct state.  Implicit states and conditional fall throughs are always dangerous.  It also results in a lot more code which become less readable.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this:

```
- (void)setCharacterLeftFlag:flag {
    if ( flag ) {
          characterLeftView.layer.hidden = NO;
          characterRightView.layer.hidden = YES;
     }
     else {
          characterLeftView.layer.hidden = YES;
          characterRightView.layer.hidden = NO;
     }
}
```

this is your setter.  Now, the OS may not even call drawRect, if it sees that the layer is hidden, and doesn't need to be redrawn.

Comment: You are correct.  As with so many people, I am relatively new to Cocoa and CoreAnimation.  I realized shortly after posting that 1) calling setHidden as often as you like does not directly effect the performance and 2) follow the pattern you describe above and do everything in the state mutators, and 3) do not do anything in drawRect: if you do not have to.  I was forcing the call to drawRect by issuing the setNeedsDisplay.

Comment: In fact, you never know when a mutator would actually turn around and call drawRect itself!  More likely it would call setNeedsDisplay.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz will probably optimize setting `hidden =  YES` on a hidden layer, but if you really want to find out you should benchmark.